# Adding Parameterization (Search Functionality) to DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to add a search box to my Windows Form which will update the content of a DataGridView.  I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hbsty6z7(v=vs.120).aspx but VS2012 doesn't have a "Data Menu" like they're mentioning in the "Adding Parameterization (Search Functionality) to the Query" section. MSDN seems to keep mentioning this "Data Menu" even though they removed the menu.

I can't find the Wizard it's mentioning and they don't give any code examples.  I tend to use Wizards once and then read the code they generate so I can do it myself.  So, I'd love to see an explanation of parameterized queries so I can be smarter and if that fails, a way to open the "Search Criteria Builder Dialog Box" in relation to my DataGridView.

I'm using VS2012, VB.NET, Win8.1, SQL-Server

Comment: They are talking about the Data menu on the VS main menu.  Thw `Add Query` option will be missing until you do some of the preceeding steps, and then it is disabled unless a control using the data source is selected.  It sounds like they are talking about a menu on the DGV but they arent.

Comment: In VS2012 I don't see a "Data" menu on the main menu list (File, Edit, View etc)... Are you using 2010 or older?

Comment: Maybe you customized it away? If so, you may need to reset it.  Or right click on the toolbar/menu and turn on the `Data` toolbar.